# playwright locator.selectOption using an array of values

Tags: javascript, playwright, webautomation

I read the playwright documentation concerning [locator.selectOption](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-select-option), however it seems a bit incomplete as I still have the following question, which of `label` or `value` does the selectOption use when it receives an array as its parameter?

more info:

The page gives the following examples:

```
// single selection matching the value
element.selectOption('blue');

// single selection matching the label
element.selectOption({ label: 'Blue' });

// multiple selection
element.selectOption(['red', 'green', 'blue']);
```

But, suppose my select is:

```
<select id="state" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Would the following work?  `page.locator('#state').selectOption([ "Alabama", "Arkansas" ]);`

Or would I need to do: `page.locator('#state').selectOption([ "AL", "AR" ]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs says `String values are equivalent to {value:'string'}`, So it would be the equivalent to `page.locator('#state').selectOption([ "AL", "AR" ]);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with

```
element.selectOption({ label: [ "Alabama", "Arkansas" ] });
```